# Stopping an Observable when a next is available

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following things:

```
IObservable<A> as_;
Func<A, IObservable<B>> getbs;
```

`getbs` is a function that returns an infinte observable of `B`s.

I would like to get an `IObservable<B>` that "switches" to the next `IObservable<B>` as soon as the next `A` in as is "available".

Something like `as_.SelectMany(getbs)` won't work, because it will keep getting `B`s from the first `A`, as the sequence never naturally terminates.

Comment: Other languages rx implementations have a function called FlatMapLatest. I wonder why it is missing from the .net version

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful to post valid C#.

Comment: Fixed @Enigmativity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectMany` is like a `Select` followed by a `Merge`. You need to use `Select` with your function then [`Switch`](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#Switch).

```
IObservable<int> a = Observable.Generate(0, _ => true, i => i + 1, i => i, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
Func<int, IObservable<string>> selector = i => Observable.Generate(1, _ => true, j => j + 1, j => $"{i} x {j}", _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));

a.Select(selector).Switch().Subscribe(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```